# Drupal 8: Custom views filter

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have a view that gathers all the nodes built in my Gallery Hours content type.  The content type has a field called View Order that I use for another view that displays the list of gallery hours in that order.  What I am trying to do is to build another view that checks for the gallery hours for today.  For instance, today is Tuesday, so I would like the view to display the gallery hours for Tuesday.

My thought was to create a custom filter option that compares the numeric value of a field, such as my View Order field which is set to 1=Sunday, 2=Monday, etc., with DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%N"). This is my first foray into custom Drupal module development and am spinning my wheels.  Any and all suggestions welcome.

The one thing I think I have correct are my yaml files.

todaysdate.info.yml

```html
name: Todays Date Filter module
description: 'Creates a filter to search by todays day of the week.'
type: module
core: 8.x
package: SMA Modules
```

todaysdate.routing.yml

```html
todaysdate:
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\todaysdate\Plugin\Filter\todays_date_handler_filter_numeric::operators
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Where I am really confused is where to go from there.  I have created a PHP file with my class for the filter, but where does that go? Can it be at the same level as my yaml file or do I need to put it in a specific directory depending on if it is a filter or a field?  I currently have it in todaysdate\src\Plugin\Filter

Anyhoo, this is my attempt at creating the filter.

todays_date_handler_filter_numeric.php

```html
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Provides views filter option for the Todays Date module.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("todaysdate_views_query_alter")
 */

namespace Drupal\todaysdate\Plugin\Filter;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\NumericFilter;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\InOperator;

class todays_date_handler_filter_numeric extends NumericFilter {
  function operators(){
    $operators = parent::operators();
    $operators += array(
      'todays date' => array(
        'title' => $this->t('Is this day of the week'),
        'short' => $this->t('todays date'),
        'method' => 'op_day_of_week',
        'values' => 0,
      )
    );
    return $operators;

    function op_day_of_week($field) {
      $this->query->addWhereExpression($this->options['group'], 'DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%N")');
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you all in advance for any assistance you can provide.  I can't tell you how many times StackOverflow has helped me in the past.

Comment: you will have better luck asking here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have posted there as well.